# How to make a wrapper function for Python file executed in R

Tags: python, r, function, connection, wrapper

I have been learning this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s42003-020-01247-y#code-availability. I want to reproduce the result using the code provided by the author. The codes are available here https://github.com/almaan/stereoscope. However, it is developed using Python, while I am familiar with R and want to run those py script using R. Basically, I want to make a wrapper function that takes the input which is whatever the input used for the python script, such as dataframe, matrix etc and want see the output obtained from this function. Since the modules and packaged developed in Python and complicated, I want to make the function should look like

```
wrapper <- function(input depends on the input for the .py file) {
    python_script <- py_run_file("script.py")
    return(python_script)
}
```

The function I want is a function that connect the R to the .py script and then the function get the result from the .py script and show the output in R. I have tried using py_run_file("script.py") directly and the error is "could not find function "py_run_file". I have tried to install and load the library reticulate to make py_run_file works , but failed. The error is

> library(reticulate)
> Error in value[3L] :
> Package ‘reticulate’ version 1.18 cannot be unloaded:
> Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘reticulate’ is imported by ‘leiden’, ‘Seurat’ so cannot be unloaded".

This is my first time trying something like this and I have no idea what to do. Please help anyone who has experience about it? Thank you